# representing graph using relational database

Tags: database, graph

I need to represent graph information with relational database.

Let's say, a is connected to b, c, and d.

```
a -- b
|_ c
|_ d
```

I can have a node table for a, b, c, and d, and I can also have a link table (FROM, TO) -> (a,b), (a,c), (a,d).
For other implementation there might be a way to store the link info as (a,b,c,d), but the number of elements in the table is variable.

- Q1 : Is there a way to represent variable elements in a table?
- Q2 : Is there any general way to represent the graph structure using relational database?

Comment: What kind of queries do you need to do? That _might_ change the way you store them...

Comment: By "database" do you actually mean "relational database"? If not, a [Graph Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database) would be the obvious choice.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Q1 : Is there a way to represent variable elements in a [database] table?

I assume you mean something like this?

```
 from | to_1 | to_2 | to_3 | to_4 | to_5 | etc...
 1    | 2    | 3    | 4    | NULL | NULL | etc...
```

This is not a good idea. It violates [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

> Q2 : Is there any general way to represent the graph structure using database?

For a directed graph you can use a table `edges` with two columns:

```
nodeid_from nodeid_to
1           2
1           3
1           4
```

If there is any extra information about each node (such as a node name) this can be stored in another table `nodes`.

If your graph is undirected you have two choices:

- store both directions (i.e. store 1->2 and 2->1)
- use a constraint that `nodeid_from` must be less than `nodeid_to` (i.e. store 1->2 but 2->1 is implied).

The former requires twice the storage space but can make querying easier and faster.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the two tables route mentioned by Mark take a look at the following link:

http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/hierarchical-data-database/2

This article basically preorders the elements in the tree assigning left and right values.  You are then able to select portions or all of the tree using a single select statement.

```
Node | lft | rght
-----------------
  A  |  0  |  7
  B  |  1  |  2
  C  |  3  |  4
  D  |  5  |  6
```

EDIT:  If you are going to be updating the tree heavily this is not an optimum solution as the whole tree must be re-numbered

Comment: Trees are a bit different than directed or undirected graphs but this is a good reference if you need trees.

Answer (score 1):

I have stored multiple "TO" nodes in a relational representation of a graph structure. I was able to do this because my graph was directed. This meant that if I wanted to know what nodes "A" was connected to, I only needed to select a single record from my table of connections. I stored the TO nodes in an easy-to-parse string and it worked great, with a class that could manage the conversion from string to collection and back.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at dedicated graph databases, as nawroth suggests. One example would be the "Trinity" Database, suited for very large datasets. But there are others.

Listen to the [podcast by Scott Hanselman on Hanselminutes about Trinity](http://hanselminutes.com/280/microsoft-research-trinity-is-a-graph-database-and-a-distributed-parallel-platform-for-gra). Here is the [text transcript.](http://s3.amazonaws.com/hanselminutes/hanselminutes_0280.pdf)