# Graph Databases vs Relational Database Time and Space Complexity

Tags: relational-database, graph-databases

What's the time complexity for transversals for graph and relational databases?

Answer (score 2):

What's faster, a computer or algebra?

The relational model is a way of *thinking* about data, a way to *represent* data to the *user*.  It says *nothing* about implementation.  To ask about the time complexity of a relational database is like asking about the time complexity of `f(x)`.

No SQL DBMS I've worked with used linear arrays of tuples to store the data.  They all use some kind of tree: B-tree, B+tree.  A tree is a graph.  Ergo, the *physical* advantage that graph databases claim is based on, well, nothing if you ask me.

SQL DBMSs have in the last few years added support for so-called recursive queries.  Efficient execution of those queries presents no theoretical problem, and I've seen it done.  But the query optimizer has to support it for it to work well, and I wouldn't be surprised if the open-source projects have some work to do in that area.

In choosing your weapon, ask not about "relational databases" but about support for recursive query processing in particular implementations,

Be careful of false symmetry, though.  There's a fairly long list of thing missing from "graph databases".  For example, the relational model is based on an algebra, which is what SQL is based on (mostly, loosely). Graph theory lacks such an algebra and consequently a good manipulation language.  There's a similar story for constraint enforcement, and for transactions.

Answer (score 1):

A (perhaps the) key point of graph databases is to not have to do any joins for traversals.

Answer (score 0):

O(N) for both?

A graph DB has a table at its core (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2968931/623735). And RDBs have evolved to be very efficient at handling tables. So most large GDBs with persistent storage use an RDB to store the node tables. The GDB just stacks the id's for all your conventional data table rows into a single table of "nodes" (grouped and sorted for efficient indexing). The GDB magic is in the efficient algorithms for walking/exploring the graph.

So I don't think a GDB really does a join on two tables (traversal) in the same way an RDBMS does for the same sort of query on the same sort of data. A GDB just walks from one node (row in the node table) to another in a linked-list sort-of way. Once it finds the node(s) you queried for it then does a single "traversal" to the node property table to retrieve the information you queried for (name, rank, serial number ;).